# Elixir: Streaming into runs

Tags: stream, elixir

I'd like to **stream** a list (pre-sorted) such as

> [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4]

so it becomes split into runs like this

> [[1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[3,3],[ 4]]

is there a neat way of doing this?

I've been studying:
[Stream.transform](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#transform/3),
[Stream.take_while](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#take_while/2),
[Enum.split_while](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#split_while/2),
[Enum.partition](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#partition/2),
[Enum.flat_map_reduce](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map_reduce/3)

In the end I need to extend the answer from lists of numbers to tuples that contain numbers

Comment: I think your best shot is to try something like `zip`ping the list with itself shifted by one, so that you get a list with tuples containing an element and its successor. Once you have that, you could `scan` in order to build the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `Enum.chunk_by/2` (there's also a `Stream` version) does the trick:

```
iex(1)> [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4] |> Enum.chunk_by(fn(x) -> x end)
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4]]
```

Or with capture syntax:

```
iex(2)> [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4] |> Enum.chunk_by(&(&1))
```

Comment: sasajuric excellent!  I'd not seen chunk_by using a fn - in the docs.  It works also  using Stream.chunk_by(fn(x) -> x end)  - which is my case.  I consider yours as the Answer,

Answer (score 5):

I would use `Stream.chunk_by`:

```
Stream.chunk_by(nums, fn num -> num end) |> Enum.to_list
#> [[1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3], [4]]]
```

Easy!

Comment: Damn, I wish answers refreshed before posting :/

Comment: It's the fact that you answered the question well that counts sir!

Comment: I love the fact that the Elixir people here seem very relaxed. I have often seen hot debates about who answered first, people harshly downvoting the alleged „cheater“ and so on. Let's keep it that way ;-)

Comment: That's because we know how concurrency works, and we're aware of race conditions :-D